# Using a Join to find a specific value between 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Is there a better way to write this so it will work?

```sql
Select * 
From PokerClasses, TendonClasses, CornhillClasses Join ClassesCodes Using (ClassCode) 
Where ClassName = 'Zumba;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to join the first 2 tables together, and then join the 3rd table in with the new table created from the first 2 tables.

```
SELECT t1.col, t3.col FROM table1 join table2 ON table1.primarykey = table2.foreignkey
                              join table3 ON table2.primarykey = table3.foreignkey
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-join-three-tables-in-sql-query-mysql-sqlserver.html

---

I threw this together real fast to explain the concept some more, but you'll want to change the fields so that they're appropriate for your database.

```
SELECT TC.id, TC.day, PC.id, PC.day
FROM tendonclasses TC
JOIN classescodes CC ON TC.class = CC.classID
JOIN pokerclasses PC ON PC.class = CC.classID
WHERE CC.ClassName = 'Zumba';
```

^You can use SELECT * if you're literally wanting to grab ALL of the fields when you run this, or swap out the * with the particular field names you want to retrieve from the individual tables. Then you can echo out the results from there. If you don't plan to use ALL of the fields in your results, it's not a good idea to use SELECT *, but rather just the fields you'll need.

Comment: all 3 tables are connected to the ClassesCode table...I want to find all the columns that are related to a specific value and echo it on the screen!

Comment: I assume that with your ClassesCode table, it is simply listing each of the various classes and assigning each their own unique ID, and then in your other tables, it is assigning that unique ID to a field to signify what class is being held at that location? Then you're wanting to look at ALL of the locations and see which one is holding a particular class? Throw some more specific information my way about your database, and I'll happily assist further.

Comment: I updated my answer for you. It should help you out with what you're trying to do. If you give me more information, I'll adjust my answer more accordingly to your particular problem.